# If/then python for classifying existing field values to a new field

Tags: python, field-calculator

I'd like to have a tool or quick python script to classify an existing number field to a new text field.  For example I have a roads layer that has a type identifier as a coded number and I would like to create a new field that described the number code as text.  So say the existing field 'FCODE" had code "210" , and I want to write "Highway" in a new field "Type" and do that for multiple number-text pairs. I could select by attribute and classify that way but it would be nice to do it all in one step.

Comment: I answer a question that is almost the same here:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151591/53920

Answer (score 1):

If you want this as a python script, then you could do something with an update cursor...

```
inputData = "" #Needs to be the full path
codeField = ""
updateField = ""

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputData, [codeField, updateField]) as updateRows:
    for row in updateRows:
        if row[0] == "TestValue1":
            row[1] = "NewValue"
        elif #... etc
        else:
            #If you want, put something here to catch any values outside of your test
        updateRows.updateRow(row)
```

You could also do it in the field calculator using a code block, make sure to check off the python Parser and select "Show Codeblock". In the Code Block box put:

```
def test(testField):
    if testField == "TestValue1":
        return "NewValue"
    elif testField == "TestValue2"
        return "NewValue2"
    elif #... etc
```

Then where it says "FIELD NAME =" (the update field) put:

```
test(!testFieldName!)
```